# Get Widget Instance Title

Tags: magento-1.9, php, page-title, widget-instance

I'm creating a template for a widget and would like to echo the widget title in my PHP code. What is the proper way of doing that?

The following does not work:

```
<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>
```

Note: this is part of a custom PHTML file in my theme.

Comment: I tried adding the following before this line, but it didn't help:

<?php $_widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widgetId); ?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $widgetId =1;
$widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widgetId);
echo $widget->getTitle(); ?>
```

Try this it's working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $widgetId =1;?>
<?php $widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widgetId)); ?>
<?php echo $widget->getTitle()); ?>
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Update ans pls check

Comment: That just dumped an array with no values

Comment: pls add your widget Id in var $widgetId for eg. <?php $widgetId =1;?>

Comment: OK, that works by specifying the exact widget ID. However, I need to load the current widget ID dynamically. If I can do that, this solution will work.

Comment: are you load any custom phtml  file?

Comment: Yes, this is part of a custom PHTML file in my theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33354/discussion-between-abdul-and-michael-yaeger).

Comment: I was not able to get any workable solution for specific use case from the mentioned chat.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps Michael,
been trying to do the very same thing today.
Eventually came up with a (convoluted) way of doing it... i'm not saying its the best, but this is how i got it done:

**MySQL Method**

```
SELECT wi.*
FROM widget_instance wi
LEFT JOIN widget_instance_page wip ON wip.instance_id = wi.instance_id
LEFT JOIN widget_instance_page_layout wipl ON wipl.page_id = wip.page_id
LEFT JOIN core_layout_update clu ON clu.layout_update_id = wipl.layout_update_id
WHERE clu.xml LIKE "%<name>unique_id</name><value>UNIQUE_ID</value>%"
```

---

**PHP Method**

```
 $unique_id = $this->getUniqueId();

$collection = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
  ->join(array("wip" => "widget_instance_page"), "main_table.instance_id = wip.instance_id")
  ->join(array("wipl" => "widget_instance_page_layout"), "wip.page_id = wipl.page_id")
  ->join(array("clu" => "core_layout_update"),"wipl.layout_update_id = clu.layout_update_id")
  ->where("clu.xml LIKE \"%<name>unique_id</name><value>".$unique_id."</value>%\" ");

$widget_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
$widget_title = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widget_id)->getTitle();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me doing a copy/paste of the PHP code at the top of my widget PHTML file. I just get an empty title. Specifying an ID directly works, so it seems there is some issue dynamically obtaining the ID of the currently loaded widget. Also, I'm pretty sure it is bad practice to run SQL scripts from a template file, although that seems to be the only option at this point (if it works).